# How do i print out all words in a folder?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new to python and need help please.
I have a list of txt files (about 600files) in a folder and want to print all the words list
Below is my code but it aint working.

```
import string
import re
import nltk
import pandas as pd
import os
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn import cluster, datasets
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from wordcloud import WordCloud 
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
from collections import defaultdict

FILE_PATH = "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\me"

def load_words():
#Returns a list 
print("Loading word list from file...")
for filename in os.listdir(FILE_PATH):
wordlist = []

print("  ", len(wordlist), "words loaded.")



output: ('  ', 0, 'words loaded.')
```

Comment: `from stackoverflow import howtoask`

Comment: hi, i think you need to explain what you mean by wordlist(s). do you just want the filenames in a list aka wordlist or do you wish to read the file contents? if the later what do the files contain, just one word for each line ? Your formatting above seems off. The indentation is missing. you also need to better explain what exactly you want to achieve / do ! From your code above (assuming intendation) you dont do anything with the filename. you just loop throught the filenames in your directory .

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO. Please read - [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas or csv to read files and print them out.

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

file_dir = 'D:/test/'
file_mask = "*.txt"

all_files = glob.glob(file_dir + file_mask)
file_list =[]

for files in all_files:
    df=pd.read_csv(files,index_col = None,)
    file_list.append(df)
df = pd.concat(file_list)

print(df)
```

> Columns: [some more words here , there is some words]
>       Index: []

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question!  I just tried a few things and got this to work.

```
import glob   
path = 'C:/Users/Excel/Desktop/test/*.txt'   
files=glob.glob(path)   
for file in files:     
    f=open(file, 'r')  
    print('%s' % f.readlines())   
    f.close()
```